# When following a hyperlink to a route, Backbone's View.render method executes but doesn't apply the changes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a few simple static views defined an a backbone application and I'm trying to add some sub-views to the equation.

When I navigate directly to a route, the sub-views are rendered correctly but if I navigate to a a route via a hyper-link, the layout is rendered correctly but the sub-views are not.

It seems something is out of scope or not initialised yet but would like some assistance identifying what.

**Router**

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "tmp": "tmp",
    },
    home: function() {
      var home = new App.Views.HomeLayout();
    },
    tmp: function() {
      var tmp = new App.Views.TmpLayout();
    }
});
```

**Views**

```
App.Views.HomeLayout = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('body'),
  template: _.template($('#tmplLayout').html()),
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    $(this.el).append(this.template());

    var menu = new App.Views.HomeMenuView({el: this.$('#menu')});
    menu.render();

    var page = new App.Views.HomeView({el: this.$('#content')});
    page.render();

    return this;
  }
});
App.Views.HomeMenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#tmplHomeMenu').html()),
  render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    return this;
  }
});

App.Views.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#tmplHome').html()),
  render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    return this;
  }
});
```

The application is initialised in my index.html (also the location of all my view templates) using the following:

```
<script>
  new App.Router();
  Backbone.history.start();
</script>
```

The tmp views are pretty much carbon copies of the above but with different templates.

Things I've tried:

- I moved the sub-view deceleration too the router, no change.
- Put a call to render in each of the sub-views initialize methods (similar to how the layout views are defined), no change.

Comment: the first thing I would check is by putting a breakpoint with dev tools or firebug inside each of your subviews render() functions. check to see the template is rendered correctly, and also if $(this.el) is found. i'm going to guess either it cant find this.el or it cant find this.template because the page hasn't loaded those elements yet

Comment: @Evan in both use cases 'this.el' and '$(this.el)'resolve correctly ('$(this.el)' resolving to a collection of length 1) and 'this.template' resolves to a string as expected.

Comment: Could you include the code that initializes the app?

Comment: @Lukas I've updates the question to include this.

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not, but supplying `el: $('body')` in the `extend` call isn't correct according to the Backbone spec. You should pass `el: $('body')` when initializing the view: `var home = new App.Views.HomeLayout({el: $('body')});`

Comment: Thanks for that, I've updated my layout views. Unfortunately it made no difference to the incorrect behaviour.